# How to show Google Chrome in the wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel, google-chrome

Anyone know how to show Google Chrome in the wingpanel? I know it's open, but just not showing up there.

[image: wingpanel]

Comment: Why should it show on wing panel .It is not supposed to

Comment: Well, in any other Linux distro, even in OS X or Windows, when Google Chrome is running in the background (even if it's close) you can see the Chrome icon. That way, you know if it's still running or not, and what App is runnig, like a Gmail notifier.

Comment: That's what the dock is supposed to do.

Comment: OS X definitely doesn't put a Chrome icon in the menu bar, especially by default

Comment: What version of elementary OS are you using btw?

Answer (score 2):

The menu bar (`wingpanel`) at the top of the screen is for extended information at a glance and quick access to extended functions. If you are just looking to launch or hide Google Chrome, the dock (`plank`) at the bottom of the screen is specifically designed for that.